# Chrome Devtools: If I map my local resources to network resources my source map links in the style inspector disappears

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

Source maps (Sass, but I had the same issue using LESS ) work perfectly until I add a folder to the workspace and map it to a network resource.

The workspace mapping works 100% - I can edit and save local files in Chrome, but then my source map links in the style inspector (Elements pane) are missing.
As soon as I remove the local folder from the workspace my source map links start appearing again.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's a [bug alright](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595347). Sorry, nothing to be done except wait for a fix.

To show that the issue is affecting you, you may **star** the issue (little star icon beside the blue issue number on the left sidebar.) Please don't comment with "+1" or "Me Too" or other non-constructive comments, they just get ignored and cause lots of unneeded email.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I made some changes to my Sass & grunt file, was convinced I did something wrong.